# ssh session for Azure CentOS virtual machine keeps getting disconnected after only few seconds of inactivity

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, timeout, connectivity

ssh session with PuTTY to an Azure CentOS virtual machine keeps getting disconnected after only few seconds of inactivity.

Also i am running a self developed process that gets killed for no reason .. that process works for anyother linux virtual machine.

I have commented the following: `ClientAliveInterval` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that it is alive for infinite time.

What can i do to fix this issue?

Comment: 1. An ssh session _to_ the Azure CentOS machine, or _from_ it? 2. What does the kernel log report when your process gets killed? There's never "no reason".

Comment: 1. Ssh session to azure centos machine

Comment: 2. there is no error or any prompt in sys and auth logs